# Gcc.exe not installed error not letting me install sqlx-cli

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

So when I run `cargo install sqlx-cli` I get this error, I can run rust code, I have checked windows SDK and C++ boxes. I dont k so what can I do to solve this problem? I’m using windows 11

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `wepoll-ffi v0.1.2`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\ali07\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installitFylM\release\build\wepoll-ffi-cc6f1ac54f6b60ea\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)    
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  running: "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-m64" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DNULL_OVERLAPPED_WAKEUPS_PATCH" "-o" "C:\\Users\\ali07\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installitFylM\\release\\build\\wepoll-ffi-74b6f87d03081710\\out\\vendor/wepoll/wepoll.o" "-c" "vendor/wepoll/wepoll.c"

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `gcc.exe` installed? (see https://github.com/alexcrichton/cc-rs#compile-time-requirements for help)


warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `sqlx-cli v0.5.9`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `C:\Users\ali07\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installitFylM`

Caused by:
  build failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")` means cargo is trying to build your project with a gnu toolchain (`gcc`). However if you have only installed the `msvc` (visual studio) c++ compiler then you will not have `gcc`.

There are two solutions:

### A: Easiest: Tell cargo to use msvc

Add the `--target` flag to use msvc instead:

```sh
cargo install sqlx-cli --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

### B: Install `gcc`

This depends on your development envrionment. If you are using cygwin then you have to rerun the cygwin setup and make sure to install `gcc` during the setup process. See: https://superuser.com/questions/304541/how-to-install-new-packages-on-cygwin